# How to upload and assign profile picture to user during registration with Firebase?

Tags: javascript, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-authentication, firebase-storage

I found a nice script via the Youtube tutorial of Firebase itself on how to upload a picture, however, the code works for an signed in user and I would like to do this on the sign up page.

I am under Ionic Framework so here is the code of the tutorial :

```
//Upload Profile Picture 
//Altered code from: Firebase Youtube Channel. 

      //Get Elements
      var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
      var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');

      //Listen for file 
      fileButton.addEventListener('change', function(e){

         //Get File
         var file = e.target.files[0];


         //Create a Storage Ref
         var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profilePictures/' + file.name);

         //Upload file
         var task = storageRef.put(file);

         var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;        

         //Update Progress Bar 
         task.on('state_changed', 

         function progress(snapshot){
            var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *100;
            uploader.value = percentage;

            //if percentage = 100
            //$(".overlay").hide();         
         },

         function error(err){

         },

         function complete(){

         }

       );           
    });


//Display Profile Picture   

function showUserDetails(){

   var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
   var name, photoUrl;

   if (user != null) {
      name = user.displayName;
      photoUrl = user.photoURL;

      document.getElementById('dp').innerHTML=photoURL;
      document.getElementById('username').innerHTML=name;  
}}
```

And here is the code of my sign up controller :

```
.controller('signupController', ['$scope', '$state', '$document', '$firebaseArray', 'CONFIG', function($scope, $state, $document, $firebaseArray, CONFIG) {

$scope.doSignup = function(userSignup) {
    //console.log(userSignup);

    if($document[0].getElementById("cuser_name").value != "" && $document[0].getElementById("cuser_pass").value != ""){

        firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userSignup.cusername, userSignup.cpassword).then(function() {
          // Sign-In successful.
          //console.log("Signup successful");
          var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
              var database = firebase.database();
          //Upload Profile Picture
          //Altered code from: Firebase Youtube Channel.
          //Get Elements
          var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
          var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');


          user.sendEmailVerification().then(function(result) { console.log(result) },function(error){ console.log(error)});

          firebase.database().ref().child('/accounts/' + user.uid).set({
                name: userSignup.displayname,
                email: userSignup.cusername,
          password: userSignup.cpassword,
          description: "No description for this user",
          facebook: "",
          twitter: "",

          }).then(function() {
            // Update successful.
            $state.go("login");
          }, function(error) {
            // An error happened.
            console.log(error);
          });






        }, function(error) {
          // An error happened.
          var errorCode = error.code;
          var errorMessage = error.message;
          console.log(errorCode);

          if (errorCode === 'auth/weak-password') {
             alert('Password is weak, choose a strong password.');
             return false;
          }else if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
             alert('Email you entered is already in use.');
             return false;
          }




        });



    }else{

        alert('Please enter email and password');
        return false;

    }//end check client username password


  };// end $scope.doSignup()



}])
```

As you can see, I would like to integrate the first tutorial's code in the sign up and still attribute it to my user's storage with his UID but I can not find a way to do so... Any idea ?

Comment: After you create the user via createUserWithEmailAndPassword, ask the user to upload their profile picture. Then on upload completion, call updateProfile on the user to update the photoURL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

// The code below has not been tested but it should work or at least give 
//you an idea of how to approach your issue

.controller('signupController', ['$scope', '$state', '$document', '$firebaseArray', 'CONFIG', function($scope, $state, $document, $firebaseArray, CONFIG) {

$scope.doSignup = function(userSignup) {
    //console.log(userSignup);

```
if($document[0].getElementById("cuser_name").value != "" && $document[0].getElementById("cuser_pass").value != "" && $document[0].getElementById("fileButton").value != ""){

    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(userSignup.cusername, userSignup.cpassword).then(function() {

      // Sign-In successful.
      //console.log("Signup successful");
      var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;
          var database = firebase.database();

      //Upload Profile Picture
      //Altered code from: Firebase Youtube Channel.
      //Get Elements
      var uploader = document.getElementById('uploader');
      var fileButton = document.getElementById('fileButton');


    user.sendEmailVerification().then(function(result) { console.log(result) },function(error){ console.log(error)});

        //Get File
    var file = fileButton.value; // or however way the file path can be obtained
    var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref('profilePictures/' + file.name);

     //Upload file
     var task = storageRef.put(file);

     var user = firebase.auth().currentUser;        

     //Update Progress Bar 
     task.on('state_changed', 

     function progress(snapshot){
        var percentage = (snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes) *100;
        uploader.value = percentage;

        //if percentage = 100
        //$(".overlay").hide();         
     },

     function error(err){

     },

     function complete(){

        //Obtain the URL for the uploaded photo
        var photoURL = task.snapshot.downloadURL;


          firebase.database().ref().child('/accounts/' + user.uid).set({
            name: userSignup.displayname,
            email: userSignup.cusername,
            photoURL: photoURL //add a photoURL attribute and assign it to the URL of the newly uploaded file
            password: userSignup.cpassword,
            description: "No description for this user",
            facebook: "",
            twitter: "",

      }).then(function() {
        // Update successful.
        $state.go("login");
      }, function(error) {
        // An error happened.
        console.log(error);
      });

     }

   );           
});

    }, function(error) {
      // An error happened.
      var errorCode = error.code;
      var errorMessage = error.message;
      console.log(errorCode);

      if (errorCode === 'auth/weak-password') {
         alert('Password is weak, choose a strong password.');
         return false;
      }else if (errorCode === 'auth/email-already-in-use') {
         alert('Email you entered is already in use.');
         return false;
      }

    });

}else{

    alert('Please enter email and password');
    return false;

}//end check client username password
```

};// end $scope.doSignup()

}])